# curl to request in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have to make a request to an api. 
The curl that works is:

```
curl -u apiKey:pass -H "Accept: application/json" https://subdomain.chargify.com/portal/customers/id/management_link.json
```

and the java code that i have so far is:

```
String userpass = apiKey + ":" + pass;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));

URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

InputStream content = uc.getInputStream();
int status = uc.getResponseCode();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(content));

String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

Every time i get a 401 response code.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request requires User Aunthentication. As the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. Check how you are generating and validating key

Comment: You are right. The credentials form is apiKey:x where x is the password. I was keeping the api key in the application properties file like "apikey" and when i was using it it became ""apikey"". Thank you.